# How to validate image store in Controller in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, validation

in My laravel 5.6 app I have image store function in my Controller like this,

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
         $image = new Category();
            if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
                $dir = 'images/';
                $extension = strtolower($request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension()); // get image extension
                $fileName = str_random() . '.' . $extension; // rename image
                $request->file('image')->move($dir, $fileName);
                $image->categoryimage = $fileName;
            }

            $image->save();
    }
```

now I need validate before save image if saving without image (empty) and if not file format is equel to (png,jpeg,png). how can I do this?

Comment: Do you this `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `form`?

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of your function

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
        'image' => 'required|file|mimes:jpeg,png'
    ]);
//image is valid
```

Take a look at this: [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation)

Comment: occurred this error msg **Method validate does not exist**

Comment: $this->validate($request, ['image' => 'required|file|mimes:jpeg,png']); Maybe this works? Which laravel version are you using?

Comment: I am using laravel 5.6

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
 //first you should use the Request class at the top of your file
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

```
public function store(Request $request)
 {
   $validator = $request->validate([
    'image' => 'required|image'
   ]);

   if ($validator->fails()) {
      // write what you want here
    }

      // the rest of your code 
 }
```

The file under validation must be an image (jpeg, png, bmp, gif, or svg).